# Play/pause video on scroll in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, video

I'm trying to achieve a functionality where when scrolling the video is paused if it's playing and vice versa. I want to leave the onClick function as it is and also add the onScroll function.

```
interface IProps{
    post: Video;
}
const VideoCard: NextPage <IProps> = ({post}) => {
    
    const [isHover, setIsHover] = useState(false)
    const [playing, setIsPlaying] = useState(false)
    const [isVideoMuted, setIsVideoMuted] = useState(false)
    const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null)
    const onVideoPress = ()=> {if (playing) {videoRef?.current?.pause(); setIsPlaying(false)} else {videoRef?.current?.play(); setIsPlaying(true);}}

    useEffect (() => {
        if (videoRef?.current){
            videoRef.current.muted = isVideoMuted;
        }
    }, [isVideoMuted])
    
    return (
    <div className='flex flex-col border-b-2 border-gray-2-- pb-6'>
        <div>
            <div className='flex gap-3 p-2 cursor-pointer font-semibold rounded'>
                <div className='md:w16 md:h-16 w-10 h-10'>
                    <Link href= {`/profile/${post.postedBy._id}`}>
                        <>
                        <Image
                        width={62}
                        height={62}
                        classNamerounded-full
                        src={post.postedBy.image}
                        alt='profile'
                        layout='responsive'
                        />
                        </>
                    </Link>
                </div>
                    <div>
                    <Link href={`/profile/${post.postedBy._id}`}>
                        <div className='flex items-center gap2'>
                            <p className='flex gap-2 items-cener md:text-md font-bold text-primary'>{post.postedBy.userName}{''}
                                <GoVerified className='text-blue-400 text-md'/>
                            </p>
                            <p className='capitalize font-medium text-xs text-gray-500 hiden md:block'>{post.postedBy.userName}</p>
                        </div>                
                    </Link>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div className='lg:ml-20 flex gap-4 relative'>
                <div  onMouseEnter ={() =>setIsHover(true)} onMouseLeave ={() =>setIsHover(false)}className='rounded-3xl'>
                    <Link href={`/detail/${post._id}`}>
                        <video
                            loop ref ={videoRef}    
                            className='lg:w-[600px] h-[300px] md:h-[400px] lg:h-[530px] w-[200px] rounded-2xl cursor-pointer bg-gray-100'
                            src={post.video.asset.url}>
                        </video>
                    </Link>
                    {isHover &&(
                        <div className='absolute bottom-6 cursor-pointer left-8 md:left-14 lg:left-0 flex gap-10 lg:justify-between w-[100px] md:w-[50px] lg:w-[600px] p-3'>
                            {playing ? (
                                <button onClick={onVideoPress}>
                                    <BsFillPauseFill className='text-black text-2xl lg:text-4xl'/>
                                </button>
                            ) : (
                                <button onClick={onVideoPress}>
                                    <BsFillPlayFill className='text-black text-2xl lg:text-4xl'/>
                                </button>         
                            )}
                            {isVideoMuted ? (
                                <button onClick={() => setIsVideoMuted(false)}>
                                    <HiVolumeOff className='text-black text-2xl lg:text-4xl'/>
                                </button>
                            ) : (
                                <button  onClick={() => setIsVideoMuted(true)}>
                                    <HiVolumeUp  className='text-black text-2xl lg:text-4xl'/>
                                </button>         
                            )}
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    
  )
 
}


export default VideoCard
```

what needs to be added to this code so that the video stops when scrolling and the next one starts when it appears in the window

Answer (score 0):

> The video stops when scrolling and the next one starts when it appears in the window.

If you are making a user interface similar to TikTok where only one video is visible at one time, I guess there should be a parent component that dynamically changes the state of these `VideoCards` according to which video card is currently being active. Maybe like this:

```
const VideoCard: NextPage <IProps> = ({post, active}) => {
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    // do something...
}, [active]);
```

There is also another way. If the video elements can go outside of the user viewport, [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) can help.

When the video element (or its container) become mostly visible to the user, it starts playing and then pause the rest of the videos at the same time. This may work well if these videos appear in a column which makes sure they won't cross the same threshold of visibility (percentage point of visibility) at the same time.

This API allows you to observe the visibility change of an element asynchronously. You can specify the thresholds array when creating the `IntersectionObserver` instance. Notice that this field is named `threshold` (not "threshold**s**"), although it is an array. This makes sure it has much better performance than onScroll event (which fires whenever the user scrolls), since the callback will only be called when the visibility **cross** the thresholds.

UPDATE:

Here is a quick demo on how this API can work with React. Here: [CodeSandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/intersection-observer-api-with-react-demo-7q85qc?file=/src/App.tsx).

VideoBlock.tsx:

```
function VideoBlock({ data }: { data: VideoData }) {
    const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);
    const [observer, setObserver] = useState<IntersectionObserver | null>(null);

    const handleViewChange = useCallback((entries: IntersectionObserverEntry[]) => {
        for (let entry of entries) {
            if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0.5) {
                if (videoRef.current) {
                    videoRef.current.play();
                }
            } else {
                if (videoRef.current) {
                    videoRef.current.pause();
                }
            }
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleViewChange, {
            root: null,
            rootMargin: "0px",
            threshold: 0.5
        });
        setObserver(observer);
        if (videoRef.current) {
            observer.observe(videoRef.current);
        }
        return () => {
            if (observer) {
                observer.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }, [handleViewChange]);

    return <div className="video-block">
        <video ref={videoRef} src={data.src} controls muted />
    </div>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately the first option did not work, and I could not figure it out with the second one because I'm new

Comment: @3DM I created a quick demo on how this API can work with React. Check it out, and the video component is /sec/components/VideoBlock.tsx. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you so much. It took a long time to figure out how to insert it correctly, but it turned out.
```
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null)

   function VideoBlock({ data }: { data: VideoData })
```
I deleted these two lines and everything worked.

Comment: only right now there are problems with the play and stop buttons